# Can't restore closed Safari tabs on Catalina!

Tags: safari, catalina, restore, tabs

I have a big problem with Safari.  I had about 30 tabs opened and I restarted my computer.

Safari opens itself empty, without restoring any tabs and the "restore all tabs from previous session" is disabled.

I searched the solution for hours.  The fix seems to be restoring an older version of the file `LastSession.plist` from the `Library` folder with Time Machine.  However, this isn't working on Catalina as Time Machine isn't working with this folder and its files.

Anyone know a workaround? I had really important tabs

Comment: Can you press and hold the + button (create new tab)? This usually has a list of recently closed tabs.

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the Safari page is a History Menu item. When you open that it should list the most recent sites you have visited. You may be able to recover them one at a time by clicking on each site. If no sites are listed I'd look for the plist file and edit it to see what is in it. I think TextEdit will open plist files. If not try Xcode.

Comment: i know I can get them back going trough my history but I had tabs opened months ago so they arent appearing in my history